# Probability of Multiple Sequences

Tags: probability

When I swing at a nail, I drive it all the way in with probability 1/2. With probability 1/4, I hit it half-way in, and with 1/4 probability I miss it entirely. I'm pretty sure that if I swing 4 times at a nail, I'll get it all the way in almost all the time. Let's see if I'm right.

What is the probability I fail to get the nail driven completely in?

I started out by trying to list all the sequences, and I got to:

1. 1 - Can be ordered 1 way.
2. 1/2 1/2 - Can be ordered 1 way.
3. 1/2 0 0 0 - Can be ordered 4 ways.
4. 0 0 0 0 - Can be ordered 1 way.

But I think that since the probabilities of each are different, the end probability might be different as well.

Any help?

Comment: Are you assuming that if you hit the nail half way, on the next hit you have a 3/4 chance to get the nail in?

Comment: @Jeb No, I am not.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the event A = "the nail is not completely in after $4$ swings".
Let $$X_i = \begin{cases}0 =\text{miss} & 1/4\\
1 =\text{half-way}& 1/4\\
2 =\text{all the way in} & 1/2\end{cases}$$
represent the outcome in the $i$-th time you swing at the nail
 $$P(A) = P(X_1 + \ldots + X_4 \geq 2)  = P (0,0,0,0)) + 4 P((1,0,0,0)) = 5 (1/4)^4 = \frac{5}{256}$$

Answer (score 1):

The events $\{0,0,0,0\},\left\{\frac{1}{2},0,0,0\right\},\left\{0,\frac{1}{2},0,0\right\},\left\{0,0,\frac{1}{2},0\right\},\left\{0,0,0,\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ have probability $\frac{1}{256}$, so the probability that the nail is not completely in after four hits is $\frac{5}{256}<2\%$.